# Java overriden methods drop Exception

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, interface

**In summary**:

object A has methods { m1, m2, ... } which throw exceptions; after validation some of these methods will be known *not* to `throw` anymore. Model in OO this progression of validation stages where, as checks are run and they return positive results, an object is "promoted" to a higher level of confidence about the reliability of its methods and the exception checks are not forced on clients anymore

**Full version**:

Could you kindly constructively critique this design choice:

---

- An interface describes the capabilities of a "class" of objects. To "be" one such object, it is sufficient that an instance supports the interface protocol, which merely establishes the ability to "try" a certain number of things (implementing methods that throw exceptions)
- A simplistic form of existence for the above-mentioned instances is the stage in which all operations can be tried but failure is expected in a good number of them (an unschooled savage is a person, in that he may try his hand at all tasks human, but nobody would bet much on the success of any of them)
- A subtype of the base interface keeps the same capabilities, but denotes completion of advanced validation so that some of its operations are guaranteed to always succeed. This "promotion" and cast follows inspection of the internal state and contract prerequisites to "uplevel" the order of the object

---

Could you point me to corresponding patterns or indeed *anti-patterns* (if you want to discourage me from adopting the idea) that capture the same concept of an object progressing through stages of validation, with information about the reliability of the base operations increasing with the progressive checks?

I am trying to model this via an interface hierarchy where the operations are all in the base interface with associated checked exceptions but subtypes (sub-interfaces) exist in which the exceptions disappear from the method signatures.

I considered the Decorator pattern before posting here but it fails on many levels to model the principle of ear-tagging an object as "validated up to a certain point". I also considered "composition over inheritance", where metadata (an Enum?) about the validation stage is composed into the object and `switch`ed on.

Main goals are:

---

- Have clients **check** for exceptions when nothing is known about a given "specimen" of an object
- Freeing clients from the onus of having to check exceptions when the object has been sent to a validating layer and returned as "checked and working". Using the higher order interface means: "this is fast and safe to use"
- Allowing clients the **choice** of trying to use the object immediately, but handle curious cases which may well occur, or *forwarding* it to a validating, *slow* delegate before trying to call methods on it. The delegate, of course, returns a higher order interface cast of the object to signal reliability

---

A humurous rendition follows, even if the design dilemma is of utmost importance to me actually:

---

```
interface CivilisedMan extends Man {
  @Override
  void act();
}
interface Man {
  void act() throws UnreasonableBehaviourException;
}
class UnreasonableBehaviourException extends Exception {
  public UnreasonableBehaviourException(String embarrassingCircumstance) {
    super(embarrassingCircumstance);
  }
}
public class StackOverflow {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Man williamConnollyJr = new Man() {
      @Override
      public void act() throws UnreasonableBehaviourException {
        throw new UnreasonableBehaviourException("F*rt!");
      }
    };
    CivilisedMan harryPotter = new CivilisedMan() {
      @Override
      public void act() {
        System.out.println("Swish and flick.");
      }
    };
    try {
      williamConnollyJr.act();
    } catch (UnreasonableBehaviourException unreasonableBehaviourException) {
      System.out.println(unreasonableBehaviourException.getMessage());
    }
    harryPotter.act();
  }
}
```

---

I am fine scrapping this design and starting over if need be but I would need some backing up references to do that...

Note: this pattern of behaviour occurs frequently in life. You pick-up a new object, know nothing about it, and have little expectations about how you you can throw it/swirl it/deform it/... the more you inspect it and "try it", the more you build assurance about how suitable the object is for each envisioned action...

Comment: Do you have a short version of the question?

Comment: object A has methods { m1, m2, ... } which throw exceptions; after validation some of these methods will be known _not_ to `throw` anymore. Model in OO this progression of validation stages where, as checks are run and they return positive results, an object is "promoted" to a higher level of confidence about the reliability of its methods and the exception checks are not forced on clients anymore

Answer (score 1):

As already said, using exceptions for something non-exceptional is no good idea. To me it looks like a clear case for something like Guava's [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) or similar class of your own. I can do a bit more, maybe something like

```
@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor(access=AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class Result {
    // the computed value if case of a success
    private final Value value;
    // the failure reason  if case of a failure
    private final Problem problem;

    public static success(Value value) {
        return new Result(checkNonNull(value), null);
    }
    public static fail(Problem problem) {
        return new Result(null, problem);
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return value!=null;
    }
    public Value value() {
        if (!isSuccess()) throw new SomeRuntimeException();
        return value;
    }
    public Value problem() {
        if (isSuccess()) throw new SomeRuntimeException();
        return problem;
    }
}
```

By returning `Result`, your problem is not solved, but nicely side-stepped.

- The clients check no exceptions, yet errors due to forgetting to check for success are prevented as your method don't return anything directly usable -- they return `Result` and the clients have to extract the `value` first which reminds them to check `isSuccess` first.
- Those checks are fast and simple enough so that I wouldn't try to free the clients from them. If you really want to, then create a class hierarchy and implement methods like `Value actDirectly()` in the subclasses (in addition to `Result act()` in the superclass). But (as already said), this can lead to class explosion and the downcasting doesn't make for readable code either.
- Concerning the slow validation and the fast path, this should IMHO be hidden from the clients and handled internally by your class, which should cache things like validation results. Concerning the choice for the clients, I'm not sure what you mean, but maybe you could provide and argument `unchecked` to you methods (or something more fancy like an additional class or whatever).

---

I don't see the value in promoting, but if I did, I'd do something like

```
class Man {
    private Boolean isCivilized; // cache

    public boolean isCivilized() {
        if (isCivilized==null) isCivilized = isCivilizedInternal();
        return isCivilized; // unboxed
    }
    public Result act() {
        return isCivilized() ? newValue() : newProblem();
    }
    public CivilizedMan asCivilizedMan() throws UncivilizedException {
        if (!isCivilized()) throw new UncivilizedException();
        return new CivilizedMan(this);
    }
}

class CivilizedMan implements ManInterface {
    private final Man delegate;

    public Value actDirectly() {
        // just this, no optimizations and no additional logic here
        // as this all gets done in Man itself
        return delegate.act().value();

        // actually it could be
        // return delegate().newValue();
        // but that's something JIT can do instead of me
    }
}
```

Comment: To return "something optional" is to offload the problem to the client even for validated objects where checks would be redundant?

Comment: I wouldn't say "offload the problem". There's no problem with such a trivial test as it's both fast and short and easy to write. The real (possibly time consuming) check has to be done in your class before it returns any `Result`.

Comment: So, would you say your solution identifies objects belonging to the same "function group" (e.g. implementing the same methods) in different tiers, where those which have been validated do not require any checks at all whereas those which have not, still require them, warning clients of the possibility of failure?

Comment: Only when something like `actDirectly` gets used and only assuming I understood you well (which given you comments isn't very probable). Actually, I'd do it as I wrote, but use delegate objects for validated objects, which would provide the direct access (what's important to me here: no inheritance, no exceptions).

Comment: Actually, delegating objects. The result of validation of `Man` could be a `CivilizedMan` which would provide the direct unchecked interface by delegating them to the package private unchecked versions provided by `Man`.

Comment: So you recommend composing `Man` into `CivilizedMan`, returning `CivilizedMan` after promotions and forwarding? Isn't this 1) based on my idea (which I don't like too much) and very similar to Decorator, which I tested but found even worse? Can you be more specific about your suggestion by adding a new answer with code?

Comment: I added some code, but it mightn't meet your demands as I can't really see what problem you're trying to solve. More precisely I don't consider having to write 8 more characters and losing maybe 0-3 cycles as a problem, but maybe I still don't understand your use case.

Comment: Upvoting you to thank you for your effort but, as you said, this is not my use case. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't like your design for few reasons:

- you use exceptions in places where some action is *unexpected*. Notice the subtle difference. Exceptions should be used to indicate abnormal, erratic behaviour. Illegal state, wrong reference, missing file. If you expect the exception to occur frequently on regular basis, use different construct.
- you haven't shown the difference between *unsafe* and *validated* object. How will you tell, having an instance of some object implementing `CivilisedMan` whether it was validated or not? You are mentioning about "promotion" to validated level and some special sub-interface. This means you will have to double the number of interfaces, introducing a lot of duplication.
- use of checked exceptions. Avoid them. Actually in your case they are good since they are expected - but you should not expect exceptions (they are... unexpected)

---

So what design do I recommend instead? Just do it the old way. Interface should not indicate the ability to "try" - it should indicate the ability. If your object implements `CivilisedMan`, it's a civilised man. If not, it can't perform `act()` and is not civilised. Period.

```
Object williamConnollyJr = //...
Object harryPotter = //...
if(williamConnollyJr instanceof CivilisedMan) {
    ((CivilisedMan)williamConnollyJr).act();
} else {
  System.out.println(unreasonableBehaviourException.getMessage());
}
if(harryPotter instanceof CivilisedMan) {
    ((CivilisedMan)harryPotter).act();
}
```

## Advantages:

- cleaner and much more readable, despite downcasting
- validation/promotion is automatic - once you checked and downcasted from `Object` to `CivilisedMan`, the object is validated.
- you can use *decorator* pattern to fall back to your previous design if you need
- you can compose different capabilities dynamically using [`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).

## Disadvantages

- `instanceof` and `Object` being used
- less dynamic, whether an object is `CivilisedMan` or not must be decided at compile time, not at runtime

Comment: Not "expected", say: 50%/50%. Think: __"unsure"__. I am telling the client: "careful!". If I have a `CivilisedMan`, I know some `throw`s __become__ unlikely, as you say.. _exceptional_, and some become __impossible__ so the Exception disappears from the interface. I don't see why avoiding checked exceptions "in principle"? I will not use reflection for this.

Comment: @Robottinosino: 1. I think I had a typo, I meant "action is *unexpected*", sorry. 2. The way I would design an API would be: "*I am giving you an `Object`. It might be a `CivilisedMan`, please check first and use it happily*". 3. Well, Java is the only mainstream language having checked exceptions, I personally don't like it, so as other languages designers.

Comment: You use Object as if I did not _at least_ know they are of type `Man`? This means in methods I can pass in `Banana` objects?

Comment: @Robottinosino: I hate passing `Object` around, but this is what you are asking. Does it make a difference that you returned a `Banana` rather than a `Man`? They both can't `act()`... But instead of calling `Banana.act()` (which it can't, but still can implement `Man`, right?) you just try `object instanceof CivilisedMan`.

Comment: How/where am I asking for `Object` to be passed around?

Comment: *Java is the only mainstream language having checked exceptions* > An interesting point. Got me thinking and I found [this article](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html). I can understand the thinking behind that.

Comment: @Robottinosino: `Object` is being used in **my** solution, not in yours, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, Tomasz.

Comment: @Robottinosino: no problem, I would love to see other answers with maybe different ways to tackle the problem (or maybe supporting your solution).

Comment: I am not looking for approval of my design, I am looking for a better design than what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, going your way will be painful.

Lest assume Man has 3 methods, each off them throws 3 exceptions... For each method you need 8 (2^4) variations (not throwing, throwing one, throwing two, ...). So you will need 24 (3*8) specialized interfaces... auch.

Promotion itself is not possible in Java without much overhead.

I would try Strategy and if it's not enough added on top of it some variation of Chain of Responsibility.

So it would go that way:

```
class UnreasonableBehaviourException extends RuntimeException {}

interface Man {
  boolean canAct();
  void act();
}
```

Now if someone would like to use a method he has a clean way of doing it. If he doesn't care it's his problem.

```
Man man = new Man() {
  ...
}

if(man.canAct()) man.act();
```

If interface is simple (not many methods) I would stop here. If interface is complicated:

```
interface SomethingToDo {
  public void act(Man man);
}

class CanAct {
  private final Man man;
  private SomethingToDo next;

  public CanAct(SomethingToDo next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public void act(Man man) {
    if(man.canAct()) {
      man.act();
    }
    if(next == null) return;
    next.act();
  }
}

class MustAct {
  private SomethingToDo next;


  public CanAct(SomethingToDo next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public void act(Man man) {
    if(man.canAct()) {
      man.act();
      if(next == null) return;
      next.act();
    }
    else {
      ... some error handling ...
    }
  }
}
```

Extending this sample you could create actions to perform:

SomethingToDo toBeDone = new MustDo1(new MustDo2(new CanDo3(new MustDo2(null))));

```
toBeDone.act(new SavageMan()) <- will fail due to something
toBeDone.act(new Nobleman())  <- will succeed
```

**Pros**

- Upcasting is done by testing ability
- You can define complex actions (if he can smth and can't that do other)
- Easy to read what man should be capable of
- Clean and simple implementations of SomethingToDo.act
- Promotion is automatic, you can or can't complete the action.
- You don't need to think about every possibility. Your users will do this for you (they will implement interface SomethingToDo)
- Wherever you users will be hounted by exception or not is yours/theirs decision (how implementaion of SomethingToDo behaves)

**Cons**

- Error handling can be complicated, especially when rollback will be needed.
- Can produce large amount of classes implementing SomethingToDo
- Additional method for each method in Man interface

Comment: I don't need 24 interfaces? 2, 3 at the most, signalling different levels (think "tiers") of validation was my idea. Why did you think 24 if it was not in my request? Is seems like your approach does not address the "define a validated type" part of my request?

Comment: Why 24, simple if method throws multiple exception you can have multiple levels of validation. For method thrownig 2 exceptions you can have version with no exception throw. first exception thrown, second exception throw. And so on.

Comment: There are two answers for "define validated type". First one is you don't needed any more because interface Man is capable of checking wherever you can or can't perform action without the risk of having exception (exception changed to runtime instead of named, so if you like you catch if you don't... ).

Comment: Second one is for you don't define validated type. You define how some work for class should be done. That way you don't need validation on whole class level. Whole class validation is needed when your program has structure like if(iCan) then do some complicated task; done. My solution tackles also "do some complicated task" by decomposing it to small jobs, witch them selves are easy to read/write even when excessive exception handling is required.

Comment: What if the client forgets to catch the exception? I actually like the fact that checked exceptions signal "use with care"... don't you?

Comment: If client forgets to catch the exception it means that he doesn't check if Man.canAct() returned true. He's to blame.

Comment: I see. There is still this thing about having to check `.canAct` even for validated objects which to be honest is exactly what I was trying to avoid... isn't it? It's almost like your approach actually "adds" overhead for objects that don't need it... unless I misunderstand you.